# Python 3 palindromes in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('33.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        line2 = line[:][::-1]
        if line == line2:
            print ('Palindrome!')
```

I am trying to check if the lines of text from a file are palindromes or not, but when I run the code it seems that is only checking if the last line is a palindrome. I want the code to check every line for palindromes, I have done similar programs but using string inside the code and I am using a similar approach but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: No need for the extra `[:]` Just do `line[::-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that all the lines except last one have newline character at the end which needs to be removed. You can fix the issue with [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
with open('33.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        line2 = line[::-1]
        if line == line2:
            print ('Palindrome!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()     # You need to remove the CR or you won't find palindromes
        if line==line[::-1]:  # You can test and reverse in one step
            print(line)
```